# Load static files in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I using express to build web app. I have problems with routes or static files.
I added reference to static files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and set routes:

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/blog', blog);
```

In my `blog` router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('blog/index');
});
/* GET registration form. */
router.get('/registration', function(req, res) {
  res.render('blog/registration');
});

module.exports = router;
```

So my problem:
When I go to `/blog` my static files loading correctly (without blog in path).  But when I go to `/blog/registration` I get error (with blog in path):

```
GET /blog/stylesheets/css/bootstrap.min.css  registration:1
GET /blog/stylesheets/lib/og-component.css  registration:1
GET /blog/stylesheets/lib/venobox.css  registration:1
GET /blog/stylesheets/lib/zocial.css  registration:1
GET /blog/stylesheets/lib/font-awesome.css  registration:1
GET /blog/stylesheets/lib/animate.css  registration:1
GET /blog/stylesheets/css/style.css  registration:1
GET /blog/stylesheets/css/scheme/light-blue.css  registration:1
GET /blog/js/lib/modernizr.custom.js  registration:1
GET /blog/images/jssolutions-logo.png 404 (Not Found)
```

How I can fix this problem: load static files without `blog` in path:

```
/stylesheets/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: did you try to start the path with `/` or `~/`?

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig `~/` will only work if some server-side processing  *resolves* it - HTML doesn't understand the tilde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with express or `static` but more to do with how you are referencing your static files from your webpage. Specifically, if your URLs look like

```
<link href="stylesheets/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Then these are assumed to be *relative* to the current URL root. For example, if the current URL is `/blog`, then the root is `/` hence the script is loaded from `/stylesheets/stylesheet.css`. So in your scenario, if the URL is `/blog/registration`, then the root is `/blog/` hence the script is loaded from `/blog/stylesheets/stylesheet.css`.

If all the static files are expected to be loaded from the website root then place a forward slash at the beginning

```
<link href="/stylesheets/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If your stylesheets and other static content is stored in the /public folder, and you have included the statement:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Then your html should just look like this:

```
<link href="/stylesheets/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

That should find them even if you're within /blog/, otherwise it seems like you're using a relative path.